# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.backends'

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, torch, yolov5, pylance

I would like to run the yolov5 source code for object detection on visual studio, but every time I run it, I get the following error. I tried to post the full code here but it kept giving me an error. Anyone who can help?

```
PS C:\Users\ALLO CEDRIC BOLAMBA\Desktop\Project> & "C:/Users/ALLO CEDRIC BOLAMBA/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe" "c:/Users/ALLO CEDRIC BOLAMBA/Desktop/Project/detect.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\ALLO CEDRIC BOLAMBA\Desktop\Project\detect.py", line 8, in <module>
        import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.backends'
    PS C:\Users\ALLO CEDRIC BOLAMBA\Desktop\Project>
```

Comment: did you run `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116` or otherwise install torch as per https://pytorch.org/ ?